# I cant properly insert the image path in the database

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I want to insert the image inside username of the profile basically if users input james as username it will create a directory `james` inside `webroot/img/users/james/`  and the image being uploaded at run time will be
  `webroot/img/users/james/uploaded1.jpg`.

```
<?php
    public function add()
    {       
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
              $user= $this->Users->patchEntity($user,$this->request->getData());
              if($this->Users->save($user)) {

                  $dir = new Folder();
                  $path = $dir->create(WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$user->username); 

                  $image_name        = $this->request->data['profile_pic']['name'];
                  $image_tmp         = $this->request->data['profile_pic']['tmp_name'];

                  $destination       = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$user->username.DS.$image_name;

                move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$destination);
                $this->request->data['profile_pic'] = $image_name;
                $this->request->data['destination'] = $destination;

                $this->Flash->success(__('User  successfuly  added.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
            } else {

                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }

        }

        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    } 
?>
```

**If I just only use the code below**

```
$destination = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$user->username.DS.$image_name;
```

I get the following debug message:

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE\src\Database\Statement\MysqlStatement.php, line 39]
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE\src\Database\Log\QueryLogger.php, line 92]
```

**and if i use the path variable**

```
$destination = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$path.DS.$image_name;
```

I get the following debug message:

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE\src\Database\Statement\MysqlStatement.php, line 39]
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE\src\Database\Log\QueryLogger.php, line 92]
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file(D:\xampp\htdocs\sample\webroot\img\users\1\me.jpg) [<a href='https://secure.php.net/function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 638]
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() [<a href='https://secure.php.net/function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move 'D:\xampp\tmp\php68AA.tmp' to 'D:\xampp\htdocs\sample\webroot\img\users\1\me.jpg' [APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 638]
```

Comment: You are saving the data (which includes the file upload array) before storing the file and changing the field. btw, you shouldn't change request data, but modify the entity instead.

Comment: @ndm   how to do it? im confusing.. i try to transfer some codes before save method, but still cant make it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the directory permissions. You need to make sure the Apache user(eg:www-data) has the required permissions to create a directory inside img directory.

```
sudo chown -vR :www-data /<webroot>/img/
```

Above command changes the group ownership of your img directory to www-data

```
sudo chmod -vR g+w /<webroot>/img/
```

And this command changes the permissions to 0775 (rwxrwxr-x). Basically adds write permission to group user (e.g www-data).

Use the below command to verify all the changes

```
ls -ld /<webroot>/img/
```

Replace the *webroot* with appropriate path.

**For cakephp folder creation and saving new file**

```
$unused = new Folder(APP.'img/'.$user->username, true);
$file_path = APP.'img/'.$user->username.'/'.$image_name;
if (move_uploaded_file($file, $file_path)) {
   //Save the record with $file_path
  //Redirect with success message
} else {
  //Redirect with error message
}
```

Comment: if I interchange the code it will create directory and insert image inside the created directory but It will not insert in the database in my destination field,  maybe their is something in the code      $destination       = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$user->username.DS.$image_name;                                                 
       $destination = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$path.DS.$image_name;     but im confusing what im doing

Comment: @JervynPaller Check for cakephp built in library function to save the files.

Comment: the problem is cannot move uploaded file because   $destination = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$user->username.DS.$image_name; $destination = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$path.DS.$image_name;   WILL NOT RETURN a path or direcvtory

Comment: @JervynPaller I am not understanding why is there two $destination?. Let me know which file path is valid one.

Comment: I interchange that 2 codes as what im saying in the questions is that if use the variable $path directly or $user->username,

Comment: Try with move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$path.DS.$image_name); and let me know the result of this one.

Comment: same error in my code if im using $destination = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$path.DS.$image_name;

Comment: this code will returns 1 or boolean   $path_data = $dir->create(WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$user->username,0777,true);      how to make this as username

Comment: the error is the same   Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE\src\Database\Statement\MysqlStatement.php, line 39]
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE\src\Database\Log\QueryLogger.php, line 92]

Comment: still not fix bro huhuhu